# docker-compose not waiting for dependency

Tags: docker-compose

Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
  server:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "2302:2302"
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
```

For some reason `docker-compose` doesn't wait for `postgres`at all, as I don't see the `postgres` initialization at all after `docker-compose up`:

```
Building server
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:alpine
alpine: Pulling from library/golang
df20fa9351a1: Already exists
ed8968b2872e: Pull complete
a92cc7c5fd73: Pull complete
e871e8e8d7a9: Pull complete
e73272ec9a57: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4d8abd16b03209b30b48f69a2e10347aacf7ce65d8f9f685e8c3e20a512234d9
Status: Downloaded newer image for golang:alpine
```

...

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `postgres` image was already running so that was the reason behind it not showing up in the logs.